# How do I specify required prop types in flow?

Tags: react-native, flowtype, react-proptypes

I am writing flow types in React Native script, I am having following type checking

`type Props = {
  onSubmit: func,
  placeholder: string,
}`

whereas i am trying to put isRequired for onSubmit function
e.g. in prop-types module it is check like this

`SearchInput.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
};`

How to achieve required in type Props onSubmit?

Comment: `onSubmit: Function,` if I understand the question correctly

Comment: What is your definition of `func` here? Please see [mcve].

Comment: My question is straight, in React i do propType checking like this `classname.propTypes = {onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired}` but how to use isRequired in Flow types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's required by default. You should use `foo?: string` for optional.

Flow isn't compiled to propTypes by default. You should use [babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes).

And it uses `Function` instead of `func` syntax.